# How do i code it so if the user enters no the while loop continues but if the user enters yes the program stop, beginner

Tags: python, while-loop

```
rooms = ["Front Door", "Living Room", "Kitchen", "Study", "Storage", "Basement", "Master    Bedroom", "Bathroom", "Attic", "Garden"]

desc = ["Was it too scary?", "The TV is on, what can you find?", "It smells so bad!", "The Master    did all his work here...", "It is so dark and so cold in here... Why is it so frosty?", "The Master has his secrets...", "Don't worry its just a bathroom!", "Rubbish and Antiques", "Beautiful, is it not?"]

roomLIT = [True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True]

roomLocked = []

username = input("Welcome Player! What is your username?")
age = input("What is your age?")

rn = int(input("Enter Room Number:"))
print("You have entered the", rooms[rn])
print(desc[rn])
rn = 1
leave = "yes"
while leave == "yes":
    while rn != 0:
        rn = int(input("Enter Room Number:"))
        print(desc[rn])
    leave = input("Do you want to leave?")
```

The issue is in the while loop

The problem is at the end

Comment: just ask professionally. I'm guessing this is an assignment, you need to study and learn, ill give a hint. To get the behavior you want, you can change the outer while loop's condition to check if "no" is typed by the user. If the answer is "no," the loop keeps going and the user is asked to enter a different room number. If the user says "yes," the loop ends and the program comes to an end.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have

```py
leave = "yes"
while leave == "yes":
    while rn != 0:
        rn = int(input("Enter Room Number:"))
        print(desc[rn])
    leave = input("Do you want to leave?")
```

in there, you are setting the variable `leave = "yes"`, and the `while leave == "yes"`. Thinking about the meaning of this, you are are saying that the player wants to leave as soon as they get to the room and as long as they say `"yes"`, they are going to stay in the room. Try setting it to `"no"` by default and check if the player is not saying `"yes"` when you ask them if they want to leave. This should keep the player in the room.

You can also simply rephrase the question `"Do you want to leave?"` to `"Do you want to stay in the room?"`. If you do this, I would also recommend renaming the variable `leave` to `stay`, to make more sense to whoever reads your code.